# Calculating of roots of unity

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

$$P(x) = (x-1)(x-\omega_{15})(x-\omega_{15}^2)...(x-\omega_{15}^{14})$$

Where $\omega$ is a root of unity of order 15 and $\omega_{15}= e^{2\pi i/15}$

I need to simplify this.

The solution is using fast fourier transform but I am not able to simplify it. The only lead I have is that 2 polynomials of same degree which have the same coefficient in front of the largest power and have same zeros are equal.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I took the liberty to rename "W" to $\omega$ which is quite a standard way to denote roots of unity.

Comment: Thanks! Not very familiar with editing as of now.

Comment: It is probably better to say that $\omega$ is a fifteenth root of unit, i.e. $\omega^{15} = 1$ where $\omega = e^{2\pi i /15}$.  Then the equation $P(x) = 0$ is satisfied by the integer powers of $\omega$, and there are fifteen distinct roots.

Comment: @hardmath, the key point is that $\omega$ is a *primitive* root of unit.

Comment: @lhf Okay, my point is about identifying the polynomial  $P(x)$.  Given the dissonant title, I will refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: @hardmath I am very sorry. I was stuck on 2 questions which I was going to ask but I already solved one of them. Thus I didn't realise that I hadn't changed the title of the question to the 2nd one.
Sorry for the inconvenience and please post the answer if you have any.

Comment: @JohnKeaton The previous comments essentially gave the answer. Show that $\omega^k$ are all distinct for $k=0,1,\cdots,14\,$, and $(\omega^k)^{15}=1\,$, then those must be the $15$ roots of $x^{15}-1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the help. Solved it.

Comment: @JohnKeaton Mind telling us how did you do it?